# Proxmox, iptables connection refused on port 443 from different nodes if forward to LoadBalancer

Tags: iptables, load-balancing, port-forwarding, proxmox, forwarding

having some problems with port forwarding on dedicated machine running Proxmox.
I have create an LXC-Container for LoadBalancing and forward all incomming request on port 80 and 443 to it.
If I am using curl or git clone over https from any nodes in this setup, I am get connection refused on port 443.
This is a problem, than my GitLab Runners can't connenect to GitLab.
So I need a way to only forward port 80 and port 443 for requests from external IPs.

For example:

External IPs: 88.88.88.88, 88.88.89.88

LoadBalancer IP: 10.10.10.20

If I am trying to connect from 10.10.10.10 or 10.10.10.20 by port 443 I got the connection refused error.

My config in /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp2s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 88.88.88.88/24
    gateway 88.88.88.1
    bridge-ports enp2s0
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
    address  10.10.10.1
    netmask  255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports none
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

    post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
    post-up   iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
    post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
    post-down iptables -t raw -D PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1

    # Nameserver
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:53
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:53
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:53
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10:53

    # Load Balancer
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.20:80
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.20:80
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.20:443
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.20:443

iface vmbr0:0 inet static
    address 88.88.89.88/24
    gateway 88.88.89.1
    bridge-ports enp2s0
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
```

Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: Natting from your Proxmox management IP is not a very secure model. I would have given the LXC its own address on vmbr0 bridge